# Selenium cant seem to find Amazon "Pre-order now" button. Python

Tags: python, selenium

Selenium is not able to see the button even though its right there. Below is the code I am using.

Here is the code:

```
buyButton = False

while not buyButton:

try:
    
    preOrderNowBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buy-now-button"]')
    print('Button is not ready yet!')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.refresh()
    
except:   

    preOrderNowBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buy-now-button"]')
    # Click the button
    time.sleep(1)
    preOrderNowBtn.click()

    buyButton = True
```

This is the page I am working with:
[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Showing us one line of code doesn't help.

Comment: Even though the Button is there, It keeps refreshing, does not got to "except:"

Comment: @cruisepandey did that help?

Comment: Can you give me the url that you've been using ?

Comment: What is the exact goal that you are trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I want to check if the button is there to be clicked, if not keep checking. If its there, click on it and go further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236506/discussion-between-jabir-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @Jabir : Stackoverflow is not allowing to me reply onto that chat room, also they have bot for this kinda activity. They will always detect this.

Comment: @cruisepandey now I can't even go to my cart, the DOG image keeps coming up. This happens on google chrome only.

Comment: @Jabir : Certainly I won't be able help, cause I do not know how to get rid off bot. their bots are advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the final goal is to click on Pre order now button, until it's available, then below code should help you.

```
while(True):
  try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.ID, "buy-now-button")) > 0 :
      print("Inside if, and pre order button is available to be clicked.")
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "buy-now-button"))).click()
      print("Clicked on Pre Order now button")
      break
    else:
      print("pre order button is not available at all. so bot will try again, it will wait for 5 secs and then refresh itself and try again")
      driver.refresh()
      time.sleep(5)
  except:
    print("Something went wrong, bot is autokilling itself")
    break
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press on **Pre-order now** button, you will be redirected to login page if you are not logged-in. Therefore, you have to log in to Amazon at the next step. The code below works properly for finding and clicking the button.

```py
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09D6QWQHD") 

try:
    preOrderNowBtn =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "buy-now-button")))
    time.sleep(1)
    preOrderNowBtn.click()
    time.sleep(2)
except:   
    print("Button is not present")
```